# How to supplement autolayout in code with autolayout in nibs

Tags: ios, autolayout

Say you have the following 2 nibs...

- ParentNib
- ChildNib

You set up all your autolayout code in each of the nibs using Interface Builder, and then in ParentNib's `viewDidLoad` you add the ChildNib with code like this...

```
childNib = [[ChildNib alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildNib" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:childNib];
[self.view addSubview:childNib.view];
```

You want to supplement the AutoLayout constraints you created in IB with a few additional ones.  What would be the right place to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is the right place for this

Comment: Does that mean they will remain active with view rotations too?

Comment: I don't know how to answer this - if you set them properly they will be 'active' yes